# WSO2 Message Broker Topic Publisher

Tags: jms, wso2, publish, esb, messagebroker

I m working on WSO2 MB 2.0.0.

My requirement is to write a JAVA Code to publish messages to a particular topic. I have created a topic in Message Broker. Now I want to create a connection to the topic and post/publish messages on that topic.

I have done same on Queues using JMS given on article at http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/MB200/Queue+sender+and+queue+receiver

Please help me in this regard.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link to your question:http://wso2.org/library/articles/2013/03/configuring-wso2-esb-wso2-message-broker. Enjoy